# SSH fingerprints(GitHub) differ when connecting to different routers

Tags: man-in-the-middle, ssh, fingerprint

You can see that the two fingerprints differ, the second(nThbg6...) is the legit that can be found here:
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints

I couldn't find anything about the first(PcziX...)
So, what changed between attempt 1 and 2?

Attempt 1: I setup an old router yesterday as a repeater with OpenWrt. It is connected with WiFi to the main router and with ethernet to my PC.

Attempt 2: Directly connect to router WiFi with my PC

attempt1:

```
▶ git push origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.118.4)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:PcziXGZE5iMp0Sm9dWn5qtfd/d7a+WOxIoQEL5pT33E.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

attempt2:

```
▶ git push origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.118.4)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I clean flashed the router yesterday and checked the checksum too.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: In attempt 1, is other connectivity working? I.e. can you go to www.example.com in a browser? Is the SSH fingerprint that of the router itself?

Comment: My guess is there's port-forwarding on port 22 on that router.

Comment: Yes, I have full connectivity and indeed port 22 is open to ssh to a server attached to the router.